# c++ Need for typecasting int to unsigned int

Tags: c++, casting, unsigned-integer

I had this code as part of a C++ project

```
unsigned int fn() {
    //do some computations
    int value = ....

    if(value <= 0)
        return 0;
    return (unsigned int)value;
}
```

I don't get the need to use the cast at the last return statement since all negative numbers will be caught in the if statement(hence returning 0).

And moreover this function `fn` is called from another function (whose return type is `int`) that simply returns the value returned by `fn`.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose is to silence the compiler warning that could otherwise be issued.

Comment: But there is no need for `fn` to be returning `unsigned int` in the first place right?

Comment: @Ashwin No, there isn't.

Comment: @Ashwin No, but it indicates to the caller of fn that the function won't return negative values. Also it might make sense to return `unsigned int` depending on what the result is used for.

Comment: @Ashwin there might be; it might be that the function is used to set a variable which is `unsigned int` (for some reason). The question should be: is there any reason for `value` to be an `int` and not an `unsigned int`?

Comment: So you mean some other function may call `fn` and operate on the `unsigned int` result? But here anyway the unsigned int is converted to int by the caller

Comment: The question is: why is the caller converting it to int? Maybe it shouldn't. Who knows.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it really changes nothing
I personally run the same code for different scenarios and it appears the last cast can be done away with.